# Cross-compiling GLibC 2.24 fails with Error 1

Tags: android, linux, makefile, cross-compiling, glibc

I am trying to cross-compile GLibC 2.24 for ARM (Android) with the gcc-arm-linux-androideabi compiler. Here is the ./configure syntax I used:

```
../glibc-2.24/configure --prefix=/usr --host=arm-linux-androideabi --with-headers=/usr/include
```

However, when I run make, it fails with the following error:

```
In file included from
../sysdeps/arm/libc-tls.c:19:0:
../csu/libc-tls.c: In function '__libc_setup_tls':
../csu/libc-tls.c:191:1: error: '__ARM_NR_set_tls' undeclared (first use in this function)
../csu/libc-tls.c:191:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[2]: *** [/home/red/glibc-build/csu/libc-tls.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/red/glibc-2.24/csu'
make[1]: *** [csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/red/glibc-2.24'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I browsed the web on why it happened, didn't find anything. What could be the cause of this error?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 64-bit.

That is a meaningless statepement. 64-bit what? Is it `sparc64`, `aarch64`, `x86_64`, something else?

Most likely you are using `x86_64`. In that case, you are using `configure` all wrong. The `--host=arm-linux-androideabi` tells `configure` that you are building on an ARM linux machine, which couldn't be further from the truth.

What you likely mean is that you want to build for `arm-linux-androideabi` *target*, and in that case the correct `configure` command is something like:

```
configure --target=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/usr ...
```

Your `--with-headers` setting is also very likely to be incorrect: you almost certainly don't want to use `/usr/include` from `x86_64` host to build for arm target.

Comment: Thanks, replacing --host with --target did it.

Comment: WRONG! "--host" is the machine the resulting binary will run on, not the machine you are building on! "--build" is the machine you are compiling on.